# Программа пропускает один цикл

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Когда я ввожу первую переменную, программа пропускает часть с заполнением таблицы и выдает мне отрицательное значение переменной. Почему здесь программа ломается, хотя много раз до этого я писал такие же циклы и все работало?

```
program bit;
var 
  n,x,count:integer; 
  a:array[1..150]of string;
begin
  read(n);
  for count:=1 to n do
    readln(a[count]);
  for count:=1 to n do
    if (a[count]='X++')or(a[count]='++X') then
      x:=x+1
    else 
      x:=x-1;
  writeln(x);
end.
```

Comment: `readln(n);` *(3 символа нужно...)*

Comment: неполохо бы инициализировать переменную `х`

Comment: @Igor в старом паскале переменные автоинициализируются нулём, поэтому, как правило, ошибок не возникает. Впрочем, это не означает, что не нужно их явно инициализировать.

Comment: Что в общем-то должна выполнять программа? можно точную формулировку задания?

Comment: https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/282/A Задание. В принципе, я его уже решил, просто возник вопрос с read/readln

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, дело в том, что вы в начале используете `read(n);` для ввода количества итераций. Потому как за ней в цикле следует `readln(a[count]);` Инструкция `readln` отличается от инструкции `read` тем, что после выделения очередного числа из введенной с клавиатуры строки и присваивания его последней переменной из списка инструкции `readln`, оставшаяся часть строки теряется, и следующая инструкция `read` или `readln` будет требовать нового ввода.

Перед каждой инструкцией `read` или `readln` следует располагать инструкцию `write`, для того чтобы подсказать пользователю, какие данные ожидает от него программа.

Вот такой код будет иметь ожидаемый результат:

```
program bit;
var 
  number, x, index: integer; 
  a: array[1..150] of string;
begin
    write('N:=');
    readln(number); // заменили `read` на `readln` и поведение нормализовалось
    write(number);
    writeln();

  for index:=1 to number do
    begin
      write('a[');
      write(index);
      write(']:=');
      readln(a[index]);
      writeln(a[index]);
    end;

  x:=0; // не обязательно, по умолчаниюж будет 0 (но лучше это сделать)

  for index:=1 to number do
    begin
      if ((a[index]='X++') or (a[index]='++X')) then
        x:=x+1
      else 
        x:=x-1;
    end;

  writeln();
  write('Result X:=');
  writeln(x);
end.
```

Таким образом при вооде следующих значений:

> 5
>   X++
>   X++
>   ++X
>   ++X
>   X++

На выходе вы получите результат:

> N:=5
>   a[1]:=X++
>   a[2]:=X++
>   a[3]:=++X
>   a[4]:=++X
>   a[5]:=X++
>   
>   Result X:=5

Для pascal-online данный код отработал ожидаемо.

При выполнении инструкции `read` происходит следующее:

1. Программа приостанавливает свою работу и ждет, пока на клавиатуре
   будут набраны нужные данные и нажата клавиша Enter.
2. После нажатия клавиши Enter введенное значение присваивается
   переменной, имя которой указано в инструкции.

Если в строке набрано больше чисел, чем задано переменных в инструкции `read`, то оставшаяся часть строки будет обработана следующей инструкцией `read`.

Инструкция `readln` отличается от инструкции `read` тем, что после выделения очередного числа из введенной с клавиатуры строки и присваивания его последней переменной из списка инструкции `readln`, оставшаяся часть строки теряется, и следующая инструкция `read` или `readln` будет требовать нового ввода.